# Why isKeyInCache (by EHCache) return true when the element of key doesn't exist anymore?

Tags: ehcache

sometimes the method isKeyInCache return true, but the element of key doesn't exists anymore.

Example:

```
Element element = new Element("test", "hello ehcache");
element.setTimeToLive(60);
element.setEternal(false);
cache.put(element);
```

if immediately i call get:

```
Element element = cache.get(key);
return element.getObjectValue();
```

this works perfectly. but after 60 seconds, the method isKeyInCache return true , but the `get` method throws NullPointerException. Any idea why?

===

another example:

```
CacheManager manager = new CacheManager(MainTeste.class.getResourceAsStream("/ehcache.xml"));
Cache cache = manager.getCache("siaep");

System.out.println("exists? " + cache.isKeyInCache("hello"));

Element element = new Element("hello", "hello world");
element.setTimeToLive(10);

cache.put(element);

System.out.println("exists? " + cache.isKeyInCache("hello"));

Thread.sleep(1000 * 11);

System.out.println("exists? " + cache.isKeyInCache("hello"));
```

output:

> exists? false
>
> exists? true
>
> exists? true

Answer (score 1):

As [stated in the javadoc](http://www.ehcache.org/apidocs/2.10.1/net/sf/ehcache/Cache.html#isKeyInCache(java.lang.Object)), the `isKeyInCache` method is a pretty inexpensive way of checking whether a key is currently present in the cache. However, it does not perform any status check, so it will return `true` even if the mapping is currently expired.